# fish : how to get completions for powershell scripts

Tags: fish

When running powershell, powershell scripts automatically provide parameter tab completion, such as we love to experience in fish, based on the Param block:

```
Param(
  [int]$param1,
  [ValidateSet('nc6','nc12','nc24')][string]$param2,
  [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf'})][string]$param3
)
```

How could I do completion for fish that would work either (a) for a specific powershell script or much better (b) for any powershell script?

The best I can see at the moment is to write code to automate the steps:

- search for *.ps1 files
- inspect each file, extract the Param() block
- generate completion statements e.g. for the above I think I'd want to generate exactly four lines

```
complete -c myscript.ps1 -f
complete -c myscript.ps1 -o param1
complete -c myscript.ps1 -o param2 -a "nc6 nc12 nc24"
complete -c myscript.ps1 -F -o param3
```

Is there some better route that I'm missing that would allow `fish` to instead ask `pwsh` “tell me the completions”, or has someone already done anything on this?

Comment: This would be better placed on stackoverflow. More fish people hang out there. I've flagged the moderators to get it moved.

Comment: Thanks. I kind of feel that if in doubt I should prefer any-other-site to SO, but I take your point about where the fish people are.